# Is LT8705 a suitable and easy hands on DC/DC converter for controlling charging and discharging supercapacitor in HESS?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, supercapacitor

Currently working on a hybridise my agv which is powered by a 11.1V, 3000mAh LiPo to drives two 12V DC motors. My idea is making a semi-active HESS where only a DC/DC converter is used and connected to the supercapacitor bank (13.5V 3F). I found that LT8705 might be the one can do the task, but im not familiar with it, does it able to do the task such as charge the supercapacitor bank from lipo battery when its voltage level dropped below a certain value; discharge the supercapacitor bank when the load requires high current to reduce current stress on lipo to prolonged its battery life; during normal operation where the current requires from load is within acceptable range of the lipo, dc/dc converter will isolate the supercapacitor bank from the DC link, to prevent it to chrage or discharge to the DC link. Im thinking of using Arduino as the microcontroller to receive signal from current/voltage sensor, with it to control the LT8705.

Comment: So your idea is to make a semi-active HESS? I gather you understand (from your writing) that this must be a fully bi-directional DC/DC converter block? Did you find something in the datasheet for the LT8705 that suggests it may be appropriate?

Comment: AGV? HESS? Data sheet links to the device?